# Update a un campo teniendo en cuenta otros dos de una tabla diferente

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el codigo que estoy intentando usar, con este logro hacer el `Update` al campo que deseo pero solo me toma en cuenta uno de los dos campo que deseo validar antes de que se haga el Update.

```
$sql = "UPDATE ingresos SET cod_factura='$fact' 
WHERE control = 
   (SELECT control 
   FROM (SELECT control 
      FROM ingresos, certificado 
      WHERE control='$con' AND cod_unico=unico_cod AND cod_certifica='$cod' )
      AS alias_ingresos )";
```

Comment: Explica un poco mejor que quieres hacer, no está claro, hablas de update y muestras un select.... ¿Qué campos quieres validar previamente?

Comment: Si veo que no agregue el codigo que correspondia .. mil excusas, este es el codigo -- $sql = "UPDATE ingresos SET cod_factura='$fact' WHERE control = (SELECT control FROM (SELECT control FROM ingresos, certificado WHERE control='$con' AND cod_unico=unico_cod AND cod_certifica='$cod' ) AS alias_ingresos
  )";

Comment: ¿porque haces un SELECT CONTROL FROM y luego otra SUB-CONSULTA SELECT CONTROL FROM?
¿Puedes decirnos cual es la tabla principal y la "tabla diferente"?

Comment: @Rsistemas , ¿estás usando mysqli o PDO/mysql?

Comment: OscarGarcia Mysqli pero hasta el momento luego de intentar como muy amablemente me recomendó Carmen nada aún no puedo lograr hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo más o menos de este estilo, a falta de datos he supuesto que el campo común a ambas tablas es 'control' y también he supuesto a que tabla pertenecerían los campos de la última línea de condiciones, revísalo.

```
UPDATE i 
SET i.cod_factura='$fact'
FROM ingresos i 
INNER JOIN certificado c ON c.control = i.control
WHERE i.control='$con' 
AND c.cod_unico=i.unico_cod AND c.cod_certifica='$cod'
```

Espero que al menos te sirva de guía.

**Edición** en base al comentario de ejemplo:

```
UPDATE i 
    SET i.cod_factura='".$fact."'
    FROM ingresos i 
    INNER JOIN certificado c ON c.unico_cod = i.cod_unico
    WHERE i.control='".$con."' AND c.cod_certifica='".$cod."';
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta .. Te comento Mira este en MYSQL Perfecto me corre.
UPDATE
  ingresos
SET
  cod_factura = 2013
WHERE
  control = (
    SELECT
      control
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          ingresos.control
        FROM
          ingresos,
          certificado
        WHERE
         ingresos.control = 20006
          AND
          ingresos.cod_unico = certificado.unico_cod
          AND
          certificado.cod_certifica = 11840
      )
    AS alias_ingresos
  ) 
Este codigo me corre perfecto en MYSQ pero ..

Comment: $cod = $_POST['id'];   //Codigo del Certificado
$cont = $_POST['controles']; //Codigo de Numero de Control
$fact = $_POST['facturas']; // Codigo de Factura actualizado


$sql = "UPDATE
  ingresos
SET
  cod_factura = '$fact'
WHERE
  control = (
    SELECT
      control
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          control
        FROM
          ingresos,
          certificado
        WHERE
         control = '$cont'
          AND
          cod_unico = unico_cod
          AND
          cod_certifica = '$cod'
      )
    AS alias_ingresos
  )"; 
No me corre en PHP

Comment: @Rsistemas Haz un echo de $sql en php y corre el resultado en Mysql para comproba que está bien formada la query. De todos modos en base a tu ejemplo que funciona te he puesto la query corregida sin selects anidados.

Comment: Listo por fin así fue que logré hacer lo que queria, a otro le puede servir.
$sql = "UPDATE ing SET cod_factura='$fact' WHERE control = (SELECT control FROM (SELECT control FROM ing, certificado WHERE control='$cont' AND cod_unico=unico_cod AND cod_certifica='$cod' ) AS alias_ingresos)";